# Resampling an array of objects

Tags: algorithms, sorting

#### Context

I have an array of objects (or a list of dictionaries), sorted in order based on a property of each object, say, `time`.  In JSON, it would look something like this:

```json
[
  {'details': 'some details', 'time': 69},
  {'details': 'some details', 'time': 79},
  {'details': 'some details', 'time': 107},
  {'details': 'some details', 'time': 339},
  {'details': 'some details', 'time': 339},
  {'details': 'some details', 'time': 344},
  ...
]
```

Each entry represents the state of my program at a certain point in time.  The entries are in order, but are *not* spaced evenly across time.  A nice visual along a numberline representing time might look like this:

[image]

So we have a series of objects called snapshots ($S_n$) along a timeline, whose time values place them unevenly across time.

#### The goal

I want to resample these snapshot objects such that I produce a new array of snapshot objects, but spaced evenly across time.  A quick visual would look like this:

[image]

Here you can see a resampled timeline, where resampled snapshots $R$ correspond to the *latest available snapshot $S$ that has occured at or before a time corresponding to $R_n$*.  By definition, $R_0$ is always set to be the same as $S_0$, as it is the starting point for both unevenly and evenly snapshots.

#### Thinking through some details

There are two cases we need to account for - (1) when there are more than 1 $S$ between $R$s, and (2) when there are no new $S$s between $R$s.  The following image demonstates both scenarios:

[image]

We see that for $R_1$, several $S$s have passed, so we skip all but the most recent relative to $R_1$, and $R_1$'s sample returns $S_2$ (scenario 1).  For $R_2$, no new $S$s have occurred, so the state of the application based on the information we have is still at $S_2$, and $R_2$ samples at $S_2$ as well (scenario 2).  Perhaps this is already obvious from the above description.

#### Writing a function?

I have been thinking about this for some time, and I have been trying to bang out a function to perform this sampling given an array of snapshots $A_S$ and a sampling interval $I$.  I would like to make it as efficient as possible.  My thoughts were to make a copy of $A_S$ (so as not to mutate the original) called $C_S$, and then begin popping snapshots from the front of $C_S$.  This way, for every $R$ we establish, we continue working from what remains of $C_S$, thus reducing the number of iterations we have to make through the original snapshots and increasing the efficiency of the algorithm.

I am struggling to come up with such a function, and given what a simple concept this is, I wonder if it already exists somewhere?  I need to implement this in TypeScript/Javascript, but a solution in python or pseudocode would also be very helpful, or even a link to "hey, this is a common problem that is already described / solved."

Comment: Would not that be more suitable for Computer Science SE?

Comment: I'm not sure....I read [What's the difference between Computer Science and Computational Science in SE?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/589/whats-exactly-the-difference-between-computer-science-and-computational-science) as well as [Questions more suitable for "Computational Science" vs "Computer Science"](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/572/questions-more-suitable-for-computational-science-instead-of-computer-science?noredirect=1&lq=1), and I feel this is a bit on the border, considering I'm looking specifically to minimize $O()$.  Do you think I should post it there?

Comment: Not sure either. Looking at the low interaction with your post, I might be correct. Let me know if you would want me to migrate it to another site. If not, bounties can be also helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A_s[1,\cdots,m]$ be an array of $m$ samples, where say $A_s[i].\text{time}$ gives us the time sample $i$ was taken at, and where we assume the items are sorted in ascending order of the time they were taken. Define $I \in \mathbb{R}$ as the time interval value to space new samples, and define $T_f$ as a final time where you do not want any equal spaced samples after this time. Given your description, your algorithm could be represented in the following way:

- On input $(A_s, I, T_f)$:

  1. Init $R = []$ as an empty list of new samples
  2. Set $t = A_s[1].\text{time}$ as the initial time
  3. Set $i=1$
  4. $\text{while}(t \leq T_f)$

     1. $\text{while}(i < m \text{ and } A_s[i+1].\text{time} \leq t )$

        1. Update $i \leftarrow i + 1$
     2. $R.\text{append}(A_s[i])$
     3. Update $t \leftarrow t + I$
  5. $\text{return}$ $R$

Now after we work past $A_s[k]$ for some $k$, we never see it again. Given the array uses some doubling strategy when it resizes (which is common), then appending a new piece of data to $R$ is an operation proportional to the size of the dictionaries, call this $B$. This implies that the runtime of our algorithm is $O\left(m + \left(\frac{T_f - t_{1}}{I}\right)B\right)$, where $t_1 = A_s[1].\text{time}$. This should satisfy the efficiency criteria mentioned in the problem statement. If one was working in a language with pointers, one could store pointers to the dictionaries in $R$ and remove the factor of $B$ overhead in the runtime and replace it with a constant.

Comment: Thank you!  In the week between my posting the Q and your answer, I ended up with a function very similar in flow to this.  The crucial part is the nested loop in step 4.  I appreciate your analysis of $O$, it may take me a bit of time to digest that.  Thank you!